# How to use no cached database value as agent parameter values in anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

I am updating my database value using the following function which is updated on Startup,

```
if(location_port==1){
 update(connection)
        .where(connection.condition.eq(1))
        .set(connection.source_name, "Stephenville Crossing")
        .execute();
 update(connection)      
        .where(connection.condition.eq(2))
        .set(connection.destination_name, "Stephenville Crossing")
        .execute();
        
        }
```

[image]

And I have these values connected with agent parameter.

So here is my problem: The values do update after I close the simulation. And if i run the model it works. But is there a way to do this during the current simulation?

N.B: I do have learned that anylogic used cached DB values by default. Is there a way to use non cached values, so that my agent parameters get the updated value at startup time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Every query function has an overloaded "brother" function that lets you specify if you want to access the cached or (slower) non-cached version.Just check the code-complete API calls.

For example, the `count()` call also has a `count(boolean cached)` version. Same with `firstResult(...)`

Or use `List<Tuple> rows = selectFrom(myTable).list();` as this is always non-cached